# How to populate generic list at run time in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which looks like below:

```
 public class GUIView 
    {
        public GUIView()
        {
            Views = new List<View>();
        }


        public List<View> Views
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ViewMode ViewMode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ViewStatus Status
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}


public class View 
    {        
        public View()
        {
            DisplayFunctions = new List<DisplayFunction>();
        }        
        public ChartType ViewType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }        
        public List<DisplayFunction> DisplayFunctions
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

 public class DisplayFunction
    {
        public int Id
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public byte[] Color
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public FunctionShape Shape
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

I have a xml file from where I am populating the objects at runtime.
I am able to populate the simple properties like int string etc.

But I am not finding a way how to populate the property which is of type List in my example property 'Views' which is of type  List.

Even I am not able to find the type of that property.

Simply I want to initialize the property at run time like.

```
Views = new List<View>();
```

and then create an instance of View

```
View v = new View();
```

and then populate view object and finally add it to the list

```
Views.Add(view)
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views>
  <GUIView ViewMode="Single" Status="On">
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="514" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
  </GUIView>
  <GUIView ViewMode="Dual" Status="On">
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
  </GUIView>
  <GUIView ViewMode="Dual" Status="On">
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
  </GUIView>
  <GUIView ViewMode="Dual" Status="On">
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
    <View ViewType="Lt">
      <DisplayFunction Shape="Bar" Id="122" Color="122,222,123,133" />
    </View>
  </GUIView>
</Views>
```

I have written a method for populating the object which works for simple properties but I need help in populating the list, here is my method:

```
public static XElement FromXml(this XElement xe, object obj)
        {
            if (xe != null && xe.HasAttributes)
            {
                foreach (XAttribute attribute in xe.Attributes())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo p = obj.GetType().GetProperty(attribute.Name.ToString());
                        if (p != null && p.CanWrite)
                        {
                            string s = attribute.Value;
                            if (s.Length > 0)
                            {
                                UpdateProperty(p, obj, s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("FromXml", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            return xe;
        }
```

Any idea would be great as I have tried but not able to find the solutions so far.

Comment: @Praveen: so what does not working here ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good candidate for XML serialization/deserialization. .NET has a set of [built in classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that allow you to persist an object (serialize) to XML, and to also create an instance of an object (deserialize) from XML.

I suggest you read up on this on MSDN, and start by serializing an instance of your class to XML as a learning exercise.

There are a set of [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provided by the framework that you can use to fine-tune the XML representation of your object.